# Laravel Eloquent find and where return two different types?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

When I use:

```
$myModel::find(1);
```

I'm completely fine using accessors, for example - that's because it returns an instance of the model?

And if I use

```
$myModel::where('foo', 'bar');
```

I can no longer access any accessors or model function, or even relationships on `myModel` Is that expected behavior and if it is - how should I execute a where query so I can keep using the model's relations?

Answer (score 0):

you need to fetch the model.After that everything will work fine.

```
$myModel::where('foo', 'bar')->firstOrFail();
```